# How to run migrations before application upgrade?

Tags: elixir, distillery

According to [Distillery's docs](https://hexdocs.pm/distillery/guides/upgrades_and_downgrades.html#migrations) migrations "should be deployed in advance of application upgrades", so far I've made simple upgrades which have not involved too much change of GenServer's state or applying migrations, in fact, I've applied upgrades but I've had to bring down the application and start them again for the release task to apply the migrations successfully. I want to know how can I apply migrations in advance as per the docs say?

Comment: did you include the release task as a custom command in distillery release?

Comment: @jccf091 yes, and as a pre start hook.

Comment: In your case, have you tried to add the commands to do the migration separately if you had some simple and small changes without restart the application?

Comment: @TroyYoung at the time what I think was happening is that I wasn't passing env vars and when it wanted to do the migrations the application was crashing, obviously because of the missing variables. So far I have not needed to apply the migration from the release but soon I will. I'll try and report back if anything.

Comment: @TroyYoung it seems this time it worked when I passed the env vars when doing the upgrade. The task ran and the migrations were applied.